# Python: using multiprocessing to parallel code

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a code and try to parallel that.
I need to do a lot of operations and try to parallel that.
My code looks like

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
import csv

def get_all_links(url):
    all_urls = []
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome",
        "Accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/webp, */*; q=0.8"
        }
    for film_id in range(298, 310):  # 842198 - last id
        print(film_id)
        url_parts = url.split('/')
        url = str(url_parts[0]) + '//' + str(url_parts[2]) + '/' + str(url_parts[3]) + '/' + str(film_id)
        all_urls.append(url)
    return all_urls

def write_csv(data):
    with open('all users id.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer()

        writer.writerow((data['id']))

def get_all_user(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome",
                "Accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/webp, */*; q=0.8"
              }
    print (url)
    try:
        html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        users_links = soup.findAll('p', class_='profile_name')
        for user_mark in users_links:
            user_url = user_mark.a
            if user_url is not None:
                user_id = (user_url.attrs['href'].split('/')[2])

    except:
        return None
    data = {'id': user_id}
    return data


def write_users_to_file(lst):
    file = open('all user id.txt', 'w')
    for id in lst:
        file.write("%s\n" % id)

def make_all(url):
    data = get_all_user(url)
    write_csv(data)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/'
    all_films = get_all_links(url)
    print (all_films)
    with Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(make_all, all_films)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I have an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Елена Девятайкина/Desktop/projects/kinopoisk/kinopoisk.py", line 63, in <module>
main()
  File "C:/Users/Елена Девятайкина/Desktop/projects/kinopoisk/kinopoisk.py", line 60, in main
p.map(make_all, all_films)
  File "C:\Users\Елена Девятайкина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Елена Девятайкина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
raise self._value
TypeError:  expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Can anybody explain why I get this error. I give to function list with strings and use `map`.
I don't understand why it prints `TypeError:  expected at least 1 arguments, got 0`

Comment: You are on Windows. I'm not sure if this also applies to `Pool` and/or whether it could be the cause of your issue (seems unlikely I guess) but multiprocessing code should be protected by `if __name__ == '__main__'` as per [the guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)

Comment: What happens if you pass the arguments as a tuple, so `p.map(make_all, (all_films,))`?

Comment: @roganjosh it returns `esult = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Елена Девятайкина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\Елена Девятайкина\Desktop\projects\kinopoisk\kinopoisk.py", line 53, in make_all
    write_csv(data)
  File "C:\Users\Елена Девятайкина\Desktop\projects\kinopoisk\kinopoisk.py", line 22, in write_csv
    writer = csv.writer()
TypeError:  expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:`

Comment: ```make_all``` doesn't have a return statement - does it nee one?

Comment: Hmm ok, so at least it has now kick-started the multiprocessing part, what do you get with `print data` in `make_all`?

Comment: The error comes from `csv.writer()`, which needs the open file as an argument. Also trying to append to the same file from multiple processes at the same time is a bad idea. You should open the file in your main process and have the multiprocessing function return the lines to write, i.e. something like: `for result in pool.imap(...): csv.writerow(result)`

Comment: I'm not sure if `multiprocessing` is suitable for writing the CSV. I guess you only want the `Pool` for getting `data` anyway, so can you `close()` and `join()` your pool after you get that data and return it from `make_all()` before writing in a single process?

Comment: @roganjosh I think some problems with opening url `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.kinopoisk.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /film/298 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0320FE50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера',))
`

Comment: That's _potentially_ because they think you're spamming them so they're blocking your request as there are too many in a short period of time. If that's the case I'm not sure you'll be able to do what you want to do any faster than you were before. You could try using a `requests.Session()` (not sure if this does anything to help the issue, but will be faster requests anyway) or even try async requests with something like `requests-futures` and batch those requests.

Comment: Have you checked that your requests are valid when not using multiprocessing btw?

Comment: @roganjosh it has worked earlier, but now I can't open the link in browser.